# a windows keyboard macro recorder that is FAST to use?

Tags: windows, macros

I want to hit some hot-key, type away, hit another to stop recording. then hit a third hotkey to select the sequence to replay. Opening an editor and typing a script is too much overhead to save any time at these tasks.

Comment: The idea of automation is slight effort once for repeating advantage. If you do not have to repeat the task, no value in recording a macro for it. Have you checked AutoIt and dropped it already?

Comment: I'm looking for something much lighter than AutoIt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try AutoHotkey. It's created by someone who used to help with AutoIT, but has more emphasis on hotkey functionality. VERY simple to learn, and comes with an easy to use recorder.

Comment: I installed it, could not find the recorder and then posted this as a result. what is the "start recording" hotkey?

Comment: The recording application is called "AutoScriptWriter (recorder)"... Maybe try a search on your hard drive, and if nothing turns up, try searching it in a search engine. It writes your actions into an AHK script, and allows you to edit the script if anything goes wrong.

Comment: can you bring up a list of the saved macros with a hotkey? I dont want to assign each to a hot-key

Comment: Though it may take a tiny bit of additional work, AHK also has an easy to use GUI creator. You could make a macro, create a hotkey to bring up a GUI, and get the GUI to display all the macros you've created... Other than that, I don't believe that there is a built-in way... It's actually a small scripting language more than it is a standalone application with macro features. It's a give or take thing... It isn't limited to any application, but it requires you to do some very easy to learn scripting to make up for it.

Answer (score 0):

While likely overkill for what you may be trying to do, the [Logitech G15](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823126034&Tpk=Logitech%20g15) keyboard has the ability to do on-the-fly macro recording at the push of a button.

[image: Logitech G15]

Comment: awesome, but how do I download it?

Comment: Now that part could be a little tricky...